# How to manually call UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I created UITableView dynamically in my program.

In .h file I've written this:

```
UITableView *aTableView
```

In .m file I've written this:
in didload method

```
aTableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame] 
  style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

aTableView.delegate=self;
aTableView.datasource=self;
aTableView.autoresizeSubviews=YES;

self.view=aTableView
```

and outside didload method I've written this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [a count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell"; 

    static NSInteger StateTag = 1;
    static NSInteger CapitalTag = 2;
    static NSInteger StateTag1 = 3;
    static NSInteger StateTag2 = 4;


    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = 10; 
        frame.origin.y = 5;
        frame.size.height = 35;
        frame.size.width = 170;


        UILabel *capitalLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        capitalLabel.tag = CapitalTag;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:capitalLabel];



        frame.origin.x += 175;
        UILabel *stateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        stateLabel.tag = StateTag;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:stateLabel];

        frame.origin.x += 180;
        UILabel *stateLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        stateLabel1.tag = StateTag1;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:stateLabel1];


        frame.origin.x += 190;
        UILabel *stateLabel2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        stateLabel2.tag = StateTag2;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:stateLabel2];


    }
    UILabel *capitalLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:CapitalTag];
    UILabel *stateLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:StateTag];
    UILabel *stateLabel1 = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:StateTag1];
    UILabel *stateLabel2 = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:StateTag2];

    capitalLabel.text=[a objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    stateLabel.text = [b objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    stateLabel1.text = [c objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    stateLabel2.text = [d objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

This table is called automatically, I don't want to call this tableview automatically.

I want to call this tableview programatically.

How should I call ??

Comment: The code above is pretty programmatic - can you clarify what you want?

Comment: i want to call table programatically

Comment: You are calling it programmatically when you set the delegate and the datasource.  Then it is calling you back and you are programmatically answering those callbacks.  Are you really saying that you don't want a callback pattern but instead you want to 'populate' the table by you setting the row?

Answer (score 0):

you have to call it from didload method when starting your app.